# awesome wm: pop yes/no dialog when killing a window

Tags: zenity, awesome-wm

In [awesome wm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awesome_(window_manager)) when I press `mod-q` I kill the current window. I would like to pop a yes/no dialog to confirm the action:

```
if zenity --question --title='Quit?' --text='Quit?'; then kill_the_window; fi
```

But, the killing function is run from the Lua code in `rc.lua`, not from the shell.

```
awful.key({ modkey, }, "q", function (c) c:kill() end)
```

How to make the awesome wait for the [zenity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenity) output before killing the window,

Answer (score 2):

Awesome is written in lua, so all you need to know is how to capture the exit status of a program run by lua. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607384/getting-return-status-and-program-output).